# Using setInterval in react whack-a-mole game

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, setinterval

I have grid items that are children of a grid component.

```
function Grid({number}) {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(0);
  const array = Array(number).fill();

  const lightUp = useCallback(() => {
    let timeId = setInterval(function() {
    var item_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*15);
    console.log(item_id)
    setStatus(item_id)
  }, 1000)
  return () => clearTimeout(timeId);
 }, [status]);

  useEffect(() => {
    lightUp()
  },[status, lightUp])




  return (
    <div className='grid'>
    {array.map((e, idx)=> {
      return <GridItem status={status} key={idx} index={idx} />
    })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Grid;
```

The lightUp function serves to select a random number from 1-15. These numbers correspond to the number of grid items. For whichever grid-item index the random number matches, the grid item is highlighted in red. I'm printing the rand number to console.
The issue that's occurring is the timing starts off fine but then speeds up. The console is printing numbers 5,6,7 at a time. I want the behaviour to be - every 2 seconds, a different grid item is lit up based on the rand number and index pairing.
I've looked through the React docs and online tutorials. I've experimented with clearInterval but the issue persists.

I'm looking for any solution and cause of this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: that's not how clearInterval works, btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the useEffect hook to:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let timeId = setInterval(function() {
    var item_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*15);
    console.log(item_id)
    setStatus(item_id)
  }, 2000)
  return () => clearTimeout(timeId);
},[status])
```

This has solved the issue and the console.log is running every two seconds.